# Evaluating $\int_a^b (x-\alpha)(x-\beta) \ dx$ without expanding the integrand

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Is there a property for definite integrals of the form:

$$\int_{a}^{b} (x-\alpha)(x-\beta) \ dx$$

that would allow one to evaluate it without expanding the integrand?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you are allergic to expanding it?

Comment: Maybe OP is allergic to evaluating $p(x)|_a^b$, and reckons that factoring and using some property makes it easier. I think the question is valid. If there is some property like this, surely we could guess something for $$\int_a^b \prod_{i = 1}^n(x-\alpha_i) \, {\rm d}x.$$

Answer (score 8):

While expanding seems the most straightforward solution, we can also integrate by parts

$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{a}^{b} (x-\alpha)(x-\beta) \, dx
\\&=\frac{1}{2}(x-\alpha)^2(x-\beta)\bigg|_{x=a}^{x=b}-\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b} (x-\alpha)^2 \, dx
\\&=\frac{1}{2}(x-\alpha)^2(x-\beta)-\frac{1}{6}(x-\alpha)^3\bigg|_{x=a}^{x=b} 
\end{align}$

Comment: I think the OP was hoping for a simpler solution than expanding. This is overcomplicating things.

Comment: @alitzer, you do what the op wants.

Comment: @Alizter This was my best shot at finding a simplish solution path without needing to expand.

Answer (score 5):

Using the identity

$$ab=\frac14\left((a+b)^2-(a-b)^2\right)$$
we get

\begin{align}\int_a^b(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)dx&=\frac14\int_a^b(2x-(\alpha+\beta))^2dx-\frac14\int_a^b(\alpha-\beta)^2dx\\&=\frac1{24}(2x-(\alpha-\beta))^3\Bigg|_a^b-\frac14(\alpha-\beta)^2(b-a)\end{align}

Comment: should not $(2x - (\alpha + \beta))^2$ the first integrand?

Comment: Yes. Thanks!${}$

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_a^b (x-\alpha)(x - \beta) \ dx = \int_a^b \left(x -\frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{\alpha - \beta}{2}\right)^2 \ dx \\= \left[\frac{1}{3}\left(x -\frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}\right)^3  - \left(\frac{\alpha - \beta}{2}\right)^2 x\right]_a^b$$

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a second order degree polynomial, [Simpson's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) becomes exact. Thus

$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^b (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)\,dx &= \frac{1}{6(b-a)}\Bigl[(a-\alpha)(a-\beta)\\
&\quad +4\bigl((a+b)/2-\alpha\bigr)\bigl((a+b)/2-\beta\bigr)+(b-\alpha)(b-\beta)\Bigr].
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score -1):

$$\int (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)dx = \int (x^2-(\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha\beta )dx = \frac{x^3}{3}-(\alpha+\beta)\frac{x^2}{2}+\alpha\beta x+k$$
where $k$ is constant.

Comment: You expanded the integrand! Blasphemy!

Comment: This is precisely what the OP did *not* ask for.

Comment: Expander! (I'm not a downvoter!)

Comment: op does not want to expand $(x-a)(x-b).$

Comment: But that's a way to solve the definite integral without expanding:
Just calculate x^3/3 - (alpha+beta)x^2/2 + alpha beta x from a to b.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just interested in the possibility of some property or identity that allows one to compute the integral without expanding the factors. Maybe there isn't, but I'm curious.